# Seleccionar cierto rango de td dentro de cada tr con los selectores :gt :lt de Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

No consigo seleccionar cierto rango de `td` para toda la tabla en jquery.

O lo que es lo mismo, Busco pintar/capturar todas las celdas de todas las filas excepto las celdas de la última columna, pero no se porque solo funciona con la primera fila.

Digo jquery porque creo que es lo más rapido, pero si alguien sabe hacerlo en ES sin complicarse casi que mejor.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('tr td:lt(2)').css("background-color", "yellow");
  
  $("table").on('click','tr td:lt(2)', function() {
    console.log(this)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
    <td>Christina Berglund</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Königlich Essen</td>
    <td>Philip Cramer</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>North/South</td>
    <td>Simon Crowther</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: No logro terminar de entender lo que querés hacer. Ejecuté tu codigo y pinto correctamente un cierto rango de `td`. Lo que buscas es que se pinten todas las filas hasta un cierto rango?

Comment: Busco pintar/capturar todas las celdas de todas las filas excepto las celdas de la última columna, pero no se porque solo funciona con la primera fila.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente he encontrado la solución con el método `find` de jquery y tambien con los selectores puros de css

Me he dado cuenta que cuando se hace `tr td:gt(1):lt(3)` lo hace sobre la tabla y no por cada tr que es lo que buscaba.
En las dos primeras tablas de ejemplos se ve claramente.

Para finalmente solucionarlo con `$('#tabla tr').find('td:gt(1):lt(3)')` he incluso con selectores puros css que supongo que valdrá para javascript puro `$('#tabla td:nth-child(n+3):nth-child(-n+5)')`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#t1 tr td:gt(1):lt(3)').css("background-color", "yellow");
  $('#t2 tr td:gt(4)').css("background-color", "yellow");
  
  $('#t3 tr').find('td:gt(1):lt(3)').css("background-color", "yellow");
  
  $('#t4 td:nth-child(n+3):nth-child(-n+5)').css("background-color", "yellow");
  
  $("table").on('click','tr td:lt(2):lt(3)', function() {
    console.log(this)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
#t1 tr td:gt(1):lt(3)
<table id="t1" border="1"><tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td></tr><tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td></tr><tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td></tr><tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td></tr></table>
<br>
#t2 tr td:gt(4)
<table id="t2" border="1"><tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td></tr><tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td></tr><tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td></tr><tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td></tr></table>
<br>
lo deseado $('#t3 tr').find('td:gt(1):lt(3)')
<table id="t3" border="1"><tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td></tr><tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td></tr><tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td></tr><tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td></tr></table>
<br>
Alternativa $('#t4 td:nth-child(n+3):nth-child(-n+5)')
<table id="t4" border="1"><tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td></tr><tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td></tr><tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td></tr><tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu solución `$('tr td:lt(2)').css("background-color", "yellow");` no funciona porque estas seleccionando solo las celdas(`td`) que tengan el índice menor de `2`. Como tienes 3 celdas pues solo te pinta las 2 primeras(índices 0 y 1).

Para seleccionar el rango de celdas que dices puedes usar el siguiente selector.

`table tr:not(:last-child) td`: selecciona todos los elementos `td` de todas las filas (`tr`) y que la fila no sea la última(`:not(:last-child)`).

Con jquery

```js
$('.table tr:not(:last-child) td').css("background-color", "yellow");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
    <td>Christina Berglund</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Königlich Essen</td>
    <td>Philip Cramer</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>North/South</td>
    <td>Simon Crowther</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript vanilla(puro)

```js
// se recorren todos los tds y se les cambia el estilo
// javascript puro no tiene un método como elem.css() de jquery

document.querySelectorAll('.table tr:not(:last-child) td').forEach(celda => celda.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow');
```

```html
<table class="table" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
    <td>Christina Berglund</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Königlich Essen</td>
    <td>Philip Cramer</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>North/South</td>
    <td>Simon Crowther</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Creo que me he explicado mal, busco seleccionar cierto rango de columnas (td) y no filas (tr). en este ejemplo que he puesto es seleccionar todo excepto la columna de ciudades

Comment: vaya. Tiene que ser con `lt` y `gt` o se pueden otros selectores?

Comment: Siguiendo con el código de @hawks lográs eso cambiando por `$('.table tr td:not(:last-child)').css("background-color", "yellow");`

Comment: @andres ya iba a actualizar la respuesta con eso. Pero como en el título pone `con los selectores lt y gt` pues mejor que diga algo el OP

Comment: @hawks si, a mi tambien la pregunta me costo leerla, me gusto la solucion que le diste, nunca habia usado el `:last-child`

Comment: Efectivamente tu solución es buena si corriges tal como dice @andres, no obstante al final lo he solucionado con find() o con los selectores  nth-child. He publicado mi solución.